# generate java class using Simplexml

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I have an xml with the following structure:

```
<Items>
  <item>
    <IntItem>
      <value>1</value>
    </IntItem>  
  </item>
  <item>
    <BoolItem>
      <value>true</value>
    </BoolItem>  
  </item>
  <item>
    <StrItem>
      <value>word</value>
    </StrItem>  
  </item>
</Items>
```

It is list of items, that can be different types (bool, int, string). Could you help me write java class with annotation for above xml structure?

Comment: You should try something by yourself and post some code if you get stuck.

Comment: Have you found any solution to your issue? What did you ended up doing?

Comment: What version of simple do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to actually generate the 'java class' with an xml file? (That is what the title says)

If so, then you should look into some modeling frameworks that allow you to generate code from xml files (models). [Acceleo](http://www.acceleo.org/pages/home/en) and [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) are just a couple. But there are more.

BUT, if you are just wanting to populate fields in your class with an xml file... look into some xml parsers for android and parse the xml and just assign the values to the fields. [SAX](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) and [DOM](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) are two very popular parsers for Android.

Comment: I want to desirialize this xml to java class, so I should create class with correct annotations.